# Relationships in Harvest Moon

Tags: harvest-moon-two-towns

In Harvest Moon: A Tale of Two Towns, I understand that in order to form relationships with people I have to talk to them every day and I have to give them gifts that they like.

Is there some way to know how well you are doing? I suspect it is probably something simple that I am missing, but everything I have looked up simply tells me what various people like as gifts, which, although helpful, is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't own tale of two towns, but I'm sure like any other Harvest Moon game there should be a relationship menu of some sort. This menu uses hearts to represent the strength of your relationship with someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to know how well you are doing, but it is still fairly general. **The way to tell how well you are doing with someone in A Tale of Two Towns is via [the flowers on the speech box](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/976815-harvest-moon-the-tale-of-two-towns/answers?qid=293608).** Unlike other harvest moons, there is no clear relationship information beyond this. **[The site referenced in the linked q&a](http://fogu.com/hm10/basics/friendship_levels.php) is very helpful in deciphering what the flowers mean** and how to manipulate relationship levels in A Tale of Two Towns.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't own this game, some Harvest Moon games also have special bangles that you can get to check your exact heart or love points on any person at any time by merely talking to them.  These usually get unlocked through some work or cost a little sum of money (I've heard that you have to make them in IoH, but in DS and DS Cute you can get them from the casino for about 20k G).  I'm unsure if there is anything like this for Tale of Two Towns, but if not there should be a separate menu or an icon when the person talks to you.